# Theoretical basis for CRUD Operations on data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database, theory

I know that RDBMSs are based on the [Relational Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model), supported by [Relational Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).

Various Relational Algebra theoretical concepts like [Selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_(relational_algebra)), [Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(relational_algebra)), [Joins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators()) implemented in Query languages like SQL. But these operations are primarily the **R (Read)** of **CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete)**.

**CRUD** is the holy grail of programming, especially in the enterprise world.

I wanted to know on which programming language independent, theoretical foundation (may or may not be mathematical) are the INSERTS, UPDATES, DELETES modeled on? Does such a theory even exist?

If it would exist, it could probable explain things like constraints on Databases amongst other things.

**Eg**:

> You cannot update a single row (tuple) without specifying a unique column (a WHERE clasue).

Or,

> If a one to many relation is deleted, the entity on the many side gets deleted (the table in which the other table's primary key is housed).

For the sake of simplicity let us assume all CRUD is operated on **Relational Models only**.

The reason I am asking is because I need to do a deep R&D for a product that hopes to automate CRUD. *I know I know people have tried and failed, but I'd still like to be pointed to some theoretical foundation please!*

**EDIT** This will also help in the design of ORMs which can produce all CRUD operations independent of the underlying DB Model

**EDIT** I just found this link -> https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/a-relational-algebra-extended-to-model-the-full-dml-crud-domain This is similar to what I have to ask unfortunately the OP's question circles into a specific implementation!

Comment: What does "automate CRUD' mean? For that matter, what you you consider 'CRUD' to mean?

Comment: @philipxy The 4 basic functions of Persistent Storage. See here -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

Comment: I know what the 4 operators in the acronym are. But you use "CRUD" usually meaning more than them, Eg how is having 4 operators a "holy grail"? You mean something *involving* them--what? Eg, what is your Eg an example *of*? Eg you want to "automate CRUD". So there's something manual that you want to make automatic that has something to do with (possibly richer than typical) DDL and the CRUD operators and implementation but you have not explained yourself. We can explain notions re CRUD, no doubt helpfully, but the parts of your question are too unclear for us to to connect to them.

Comment: @philipxy The part about automating CRUD was just to give a context to my question, not the question itself. Independent of what I'm trying to do I am asking for help in researching theoretical studies on CRUD.

Comment: Thanks. Until I can return [here's a published article you may have missed while googling the literature for "CRUD semantics"](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1350&dat=19870703&id=TXsUAAAAIBAJ&sjid=6wIEAAAAIBAJ&pg=3283,4595597&hl=en).

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894724/modeling-set-based-code-listings-of-sql-data-manipulation-operations

Answer (score 4):

In relational terms CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE operations are all assignments. E.g. inserting I into T can be accomplished by:

```
T = T UNION I;
```

Any practical relational language ought to have syntax shortcuts for these operations. See [Tutorial D](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/Tutorial%20D-2013-05-23.pdf) for example.

Answer (score 3):

CRUD can be reduced to relations, relational algebra, variables and (optionally) type theory.  A database is seen as a set of relation variables, similar to variables in any imperative programming language except that they hold relations rather than scalar values.  Queries apply a sequence of relational algebra operators to the values stored in relation variables.  Read queries return the result to the caller.  Create, Update and Delete queries assign the result back to the original relation variable.

One problem with ORMs is that they confuse rows for entities, tables for entity sets and columns for attributes.  Chen's original paper stated that entities are represented by values and attributes are one-to-one relations represented by *pairs* of values.  Another problem is trying to manipulate a row at a time when the underlying system works with sets.  Another is trying to abstract over a very high-level declarative data sublanguage.

I don't want ORMs, I want my objects to talk in SQL with each other, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

"Relational" databases only loosely implement relational algebra.  The "relational" in relational algebra, for instance, refers (among other things) to the relationship between "attributes" (columns) and their values within a "tuple" (rows in a table).  In most SQL databases, all rows in a table ("tuples") have the same columns.  That is not a requirement for relational algebra.  Another examples are duplicates within tables.  Relational algebra deals with sets of "tuples", where duplicates are not allowed.  Yet, relational databases allow duplicates in tables unless a primary key is explicitly defined.

The semantics around CRUD are driven more by the ACID properties of databases (atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability).  These properties drive the  transactional semantics of relational databases.

In my experience, successful practical applications usually differ from theoretical underpinnings.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon for your answer! I don;t understand how ACID contributes to CRUD. I mean I can have a non atomic non isolated, non durable system with CRUD right? I guess the Consistency part can be related to key constraints in RDBMS.

I mean we have CRUD in NoSQL too, but not all the db s follow ACID!

I am updating my question with a link I found.

Comment: @GauravRamanan . . . NoSQL databases such as MongoDB, DynamoDB, and Cassandra are more "relaxed ACID" then "no ACID".  The CRUD properties are about putting data into a database and then seeing it correctly.  The ACID properties are the "theoretical" framework for those operations, although a given implementation may relax them.  And, even ACID-compliant databases have exceptions, such as "NOLOCK" in SQL Server.

Comment: **Relational** DBMSs *do* implement some form of the RA and they never have duplicate tuples in relations. That isn't true of SQL because SQL DBMSs are not relational. The answer here conflates and confuses SQL with relational and therefore doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @sqlvogel . . . I think your comment should be directed at the OP, who uses SQL as an example of an implementation of the theoretical concept of relational algebra.

Comment: Sure, but SQL is an incomplete and flawed implementation and I think that's something that ought to be pointed out in your answer. The sentence beginning "relational databases allow duplicates in tables" is just wrong.

Comment: In relational algebra and DBMSs (as distinct from SQL ones) all rows in a table have the same columns. When is this not also true in SQL?