# Meta-modeling crud FROM/JOIN/WHERE statement fragments for higher-level analysis

Tags: metaprogramming, rdbms, dsl

Consider these sql statement fragments for their "meta-"commonalities:

```
-- ...
FROM TableA

-- ...
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name

-- ...
FROM TableA
FULL OUTER JOIN TableOfValues() AS TableB
ON TableA.id= TableB.id
WHERE Somesuch = 1

-- ...
FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
WHERE TableB.id IS null
```

How can I model these statement fragments in library of datatypes such that the modeled object describing *joins* and *filters* could then be used in a modeled description of either a complete `select` statement or, just as well, a complete `update` statement?  That is, the modeled fragment is descriptive enough to serve both usages.

Yes, techniques such as linq-to-sql already handle the `select` case; however, the modeling requirements for `updates` seem to me much harder.  For example, not only do we have to capture the information necessary to reach back through the model to mutate a source column, we are also restricted to only updating a single join component table's columns in an update statement (usually).

For this to be worthwhile, the modeling language's type system in conjunction with our model ought to be capable of verifying the relational-sanity of the declaration and highlight a majority of nonsensical statements as containing *type* calculus errors.  For example, join-sources such as views or table-valued functions might not be updatable at all.

`GROUP BY` clauses and computed projection values (including windowing functions) would need to affect the types, possibly resulting in a type that is accurately incompatible for use in an `update` statement yet still valid in a `select` statement.

How does, say, SQL Server parse, analyze and compile t-sql?  I expect that Microsoft and other vendors have some well organized AST types that t-sql is parsed into for reasoning, statement validation, optimization and compilation.  But I cannot find information on these internals anywhere.  Do you know of a reference, especially an academic (vendor agnostic) one?

Answer (score 1):

Most SQL systems parse your SQL query using a vendor-specific SQL grammar.  They build an AST that models all the clauses in the query, by having sub-grammar for each clause type.   The actual shape of the AST varies slightly from system to system, because they have different syntaxes and slightly different semantics,  to ensure vendor lock-in.

You should be able to find a SQL grammar easily; for example: http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/list.html    That should be adequate to model generic SQL queries, including both SELECT and UPDATE statements.

What you will likely find really difficult to locate are sensible, expressive ways to describe what kinds of analyses you might want to do to a SQL query or a sub-term of a SQL query.  This is mostly implemented
by ad hoc machinery.

Regarding your question about what SQL engines do:  Mostly they compile SQL statements using a combination of classic compiler technology (parse, build AST, build symbol tables, compute types of intermediate expression, do some data flow analysis), with optimizations for data access driven by access statistics collected by the engine over time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your third paragraph about describing analyses?  I have [very](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894724/modeling-set-based-code-listings-of-sql-data-manipulation-operations) . [specific](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43672/a-relational-algebra-extended-to-model-the-full-dml-crud-domain) . [analyses](https://github.com/MrAndMrsK/Unbounded/wiki) in mind.  You're a rare person that seems to understand what I'm asking about - have you pursued this before?

Comment: Check my bio.  I've been building program analysis tools for ~~35 years.  I probably haven't done the specific analysis you want; everybody wants something unique.  I've probably thought about and even implemented machinery that might be able to do what you want.

Comment: ... when reasoning about program fragments, you get into the question of *what are the semantics of the language*  (for SQL, largely the Codd's relational algebra),  what part of that can you/are you willing to express, how do you express it, and what questions do you want answered.   Compiler theory provides a lot of ideas about how to do this in a practical way; requiring in general Life After Parsing http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/LifeAfterParsing.html  You may want to reason about SQL statments in the context of an existing DB schema; compiler technology can do that.

Comment: ... you may want to reason about the interaction of SQL statements in the abstract (e.g.,  "is DELETE table X followed by SELECT X.F a valid sequence in any possible world?")  which requires deeper expression of the algebra behind SQL in a form you can reason about symbolically.   Traditional compiler technology does NOT do that.  I build tools that can be configured to operate in the compiler tech space or the symbolic reasoning space, or bridge the two.

Comment: Based on a brief look at your offered link, it appears to me that you want to do optimization across multiple queries.  You probably needed both the compiler-type and symbolic reasoning capabilities to do that.

Comment: Here's another link that I think gives some neat examples, kind of a draft status: https://github.com/MrAndMrsK/Unbounded/wiki/Modeling-SQL-for-static-analysis-of-DML-operations

Comment: Yep, confirmed.  Where do you want to go from here?  My email address is in my bio, maybe we should exchange email and actually chat; you have an interesting problem.